# Configuración para servidor ubuntu

Tags: linux, servidor, instalacion, vps

Buenas noches a todos.

Es mi primera vez instalando un servidor vps en ubuntu 20.04, ya seguí muchos tutoriales y videos de todos los pasos y comandos para poder configurar mi servidor. EL problema es que al ingresar mi ip me muestra la pagina de apache2.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y en la parte de mi virtual host tengo la siguiente configuración en la ruta var/www/html la cual ya tiene un archivo index.html

```
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
ServerName nombre.com
ServerAlias www.nombre.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
```

Ya no he podido avanzar de esta parte

Comment: Enhorabuena. Tu servidor funciona correctamente y estás viendo el contenido de ese archivo `index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

@Hugo en la carpeta `/var/www` es donde van los diferentes sitios web.
Así que crea una carpeta con tu sitio como por ejemplo `/var/www/webmaster`
allí introduce todos los archivos de tu web, tus html o php con sus css, javascript, etc...

Una vez realizado esto te vas al archivo de configuración que muestras y en **DocumentRoot** poner la ruta nueva `/var/www/webmaster`

Una vez realizado esto tendrás que modificar el hosts de tu maquina para el dominio así que pones lo siguiente en la terminal `sudo nano /etc/hosts` si no tienes nano alomejor tienes el **vi** seria `sudo vi /etc/hosts`

Allí pones lo siguiente **127.0.0.1 nombre.com**
una vez realizado esto abres un navegador y pones nombre.com y deberías de ver tu pagina web.

Si no la ves deberías de resetear el apache.
`sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

o dependiendo de la versión que tengas.

`sudo /etc/init.d/apache restart`

Comment: Hola Jordi, gracias por comentar pero acabo de hacer lo que escribiste y no funciono

Comment: Creo que falta cargar el archivo de host virtual en `apache2.conf`. Además, es probable que el servidor use `systemd` para manejar los servicios y los comandos sean diferentes.

Comment: @Hugo, por favor edita tu pregunta para agregar lo que intentaste y los mensajes que recibiste, especialmente si se trata de errores.